# Can I have different aggregation rules for different columns in acast?

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape2

Brain afunctional today: How do I tell `acast` to return different aggregations?

```
# the rows and columns have integer names
Rgames> foo
  1 2
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
1 1 4
2 2 8
3 3 2
4 4 1
Rgames> mfoo<-melt(foo)
Rgames> mfoo
   Var1 Var2 value
1     1    1     1
2     2    1     2
3     3    1     3
4     4    1     4
5     1    1     1
6     2    1     2
7     3    1     3
8     4    1     4
9     1    2     1
10    2    2     2
11    3    2     3
12    4    2     4
13    1    2     4
14    2    2     8
15    3    2     2
16    4    2     1
Rgames> acast(mfoo,Var1~Var2,function(x)x[1]-x[2])
  1  2
1 0 -3
2 0 -6
3 0  1
4 0  3
# what I would like is the casting formula to return
  1  2
1 1 -3
2 2 -6
3 3  1
4 4  3
```

With the caveat that this is a simple example.  In the general case, there will be rows with unique names -- but never more than two rows with a given name, so my `x[1]-x[2]` won't ever fail.
Or should I just use this:

```
aggregate(foo[,2],by=list((foo[,1])),function(x)x[1]-x[2])
```

Comment: The rownames already have that, can't you make do with that?

Comment: @Codoremifa  I probably could, but suspect there's a "right way" to do it. Again, in the general case I'd have to track the row names back to the actual (floatingpoint) values in the first column.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can't. You could solve it by aggregating with plyr, then reshaping with `dcast`

Comment: @hadley  OK, thanks.  I ended up just using `intersect` on the first column and subsetting with the results.